# Getting ClassNotFoundException for GSON when running Android Instrumented test for Room migration

Tags: android, android-room, android-testing

I have a project for which I am using Room for storage, and am currently trying to set up a test for a simple migration.

I followed the steps described at https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/testing-room-migrations-be93cdb0d975 and have a test that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MigrationsTest {

    private val DB_NAME = "test.db"

    private lateinit var testHelper: MigrationTestHelper

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        testHelper = MigrationTestHelper(
            androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(),
            MyDatabase::class.java.canonicalName,
            FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelperFactory()
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun testMigrate1_2() {
        val db = testHelper.createDatabase(DB_NAME, 1)
        db.close()

        testHelper.runMigrationsAndValidate(DB_NAME, 2, true, MyDatabase.MIGRATION_1_2)
    }

}
```

However, when running the test on a physical device, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/gson/GsonBuilder;
```

The `MigrationTestHelper` itself seems fine, and if I try to create a `Gson` or `GsonBuilder` object within the test, I get the same error.

In my dependencies, I also added these lines (using Kotlin DSL):

```
dependencies {
    ... 
    androidTestImplementation("android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1")
    androidTestImplementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0")
}
```

Running the app itself is fine, storage works as expected.

What is the proper way to include `Gson` and avoid this error? Not being able to easily test transactions is an issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. It was just a proguard issue. Whenever a class isn't found, you just need to make sure it isn't stripped out.

In my case, I added this line to my proguard file

```
-keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
```

And then keep adding more instructions whenever it complains.